# Retrieve data from the class table using parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, mediametadataretriever

I want to retrieve value from the class of the object.
example:  I have one class Player_info.
In this class there is different field like Player name,Score,birthdate.
1.messi,50,7/12/1991.
2.ronaldo,45,7/7/1993.
3.rooney,40,7/12/1991.

now i want to retrieve data ronaldo score which is from this class using parse i was stuck over here from 2 day. plz guys help me out. It was very appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this :

```
    String ObjectId;
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> playerQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Player_info");
                      playerQuery.whereEqualTo("Player Name", "ronaldo");
                      playerQuery.setLimit(1);
                      playerQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                        public void done(List<ParseObject> playerList, ParseException e) {
                          if (playerList != null && playerList.size() > 0) {
                              int score = playerList.get(0).getInt("Score");
objectId = playerList.get(0).getObjectid();
                           }
                           }
                      }
```

Now you can use score of ronaldo wherever you want :) .

To update the value in table you can do that:

```
// Create a pointer to an object of class Point with id dlkj83d
ParseObject point = ParseObject.createWithoutData("Player_Info", objectId);

// Set a new value on quantity
point.put("Score", newScore);

// Save
point.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
  public void done(ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      // Saved successfully.
    } else {
      // The save failed.
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you damanpreet. one more question if i want to increase this data using textbox value and reflect that data to parse.com database server.

than where to put this code 
score1 = score + {integer value of the textbox}.
ParseObject Player_info = new ParseObject;
Player_info.put("Score",score1);
Parse.saveInBackground();

Comment: check the new answer. Please accept and upvote if it helps.

Comment: It show me 0 always.
i also added int score = player_info.getInt("Score");
where player_info is parse class name

int score = playerList.get(0).getInt("Score")

how you decide Position of 0 in list.